# Converting a decimal to a binary in C (output missing digits)

Tags: arrays, c, binary, cs50

Why is it returning 7 digits instead of 8 digits once binary array's length is 8 (meaning 8 bits)?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number = get_int("Number: ");
    char binary[8]; // 8 bits in a byte

    for (int i = 0; number != 0 ; i++)
    {
        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            binary[i] = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            binary[i] = '1';
        }
        number /= 2;
    }
    printf("%s\n", binary);
}
```

**I'm getting**

Number: 72

Binary: 0001001

I know it's reversed from the correct answer for this decimal, just want to correct the missing digit first.

Comment: Leading zero is *not* a "missing digit" (BTW, for binary "bit" stands for "Binary digIT"), because it does not change the value. If you want a fixed 8-bit weight, then you should run your loop for fixed 8 iterations rather than until the number is non-zero.

Comment: Also you need to null-terminate your string.  One way would be `char binary[9] = {0};`.  (9 bytes gives you your 8, plus 1 for the null terminator.)

Comment: A null terminator needs to be appended to the `binary` string before printing it with the `%s` printf format specifier. `char binary[9];` is large enough for 8 digits and a null terminator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your program, I only had to make one small correction:

https://ideone.com/87v18W

```
int main(void)
{
    int number = 145;
    char binary[8+1] = {}; // 8 bits in a byte, + 1 for string-terminator
    // If you're going to print it out as a string, you have to make sure there is space for a nil-terminator ('\0') at the end of the string.
    // Hence the +1 for space, and the ={}; to set the whole thing to 0 before filling in the bits.

    for (int i = 0; number != 0 ; i++)
    {
        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            binary[i] = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            binary[i] = '1';
        }
        number /= 2;
    }
    printf("%s\n", binary);
}
```

When I run this program, with input of `145`, I get

### Output

```
10001001
```

---

---

Here's how I do ints to binary, with a `.` separator every 8 bits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint32_t num = 93935;
    
    for(int i=(sizeof(uint32_t)*CHAR_BIT)-1; i>=0; --i)
    {
        printf("%c%s", "01"[!!(num & (1<<i))], i%8?"":i?".":"");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Example Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5404KB
00000000.00000001.01101110.11101111
```

Comment: In the first program the leading zero is still missing

Comment: `char binary[8+1] = {};` --> `char binary[8+1] = { 0 };` .  `{}` not yet available in standard C.

Comment: `1<<i` is UB when `i==31`.  Better as `1u<<i`.  Even better as `(uint32_t)1 << i`.